# How would I get all posts that a tag belongs to? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So the way I did things for these model set ups is a bit different then what you might actually do. How ever I did things like this:

## Post Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :user

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, join_table: 'tags_posts', :dependent => :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, join_table: 'categories_posts', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true

  def has_tag?(tag_name)
   tags.where(name: tag_name).any?
  end

  def tag_names
    tags.pluck(:name)
  end

  def tag_names=(names)
    self.tags = names.map{ |name| Tag.where(name: name).first }
  end

  def tag_name=(tag_name)
    single_tag = [tag_name]
    self.tag_names = single_tag
  end

  def has_category?(category_name)
   categories.where(name: category_name).any?
  end

  def category_names
    categories.pluck(:name)
  end

  def category_names=(names)
    self.categories = names.map{ |name| Category.where(name: name).first }
  end

  def category_name=(category_name)
      single_category_name = [category_name]
      self.category_names = single_category_name
  end

  def user=(id)
    user = User.find_by(id: id)
    self.user_id = user.id if user
  end

end
```

The above allows us to assign tags and categories and a post to a user (the last part is being refactored out as we speak). You can also get all tags and categories for a post and see if that post has a particular category.

Now what I want to do, in the tags model (for now) is get all the posts that a tag belongs to. But I am not sure how to do that ...

this is my tags model:

## Tags Model

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

**How do I accomplish what I want?**

Comment: You are missing some obvious things that are explained in the basic starting guide. Start by reading the documentation and you'll find your answer along with other useful information. Good luck. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to do this with `has_and_belong_to_many`. However, it would be pretty easy using has many through. By Rails conventions, the same of your join table should be tag_posts or post_tags (the first model is singular).

In your Post model:

```
has_many :tag_posts
has_many :tags, :through => :tag_posts
```

Then in your Tag model, a similar setup:

```
has_many :tag_posts
has_many :posts, :through => :tag_posts
```

Finally, you would create a TagPost model

```
belongs_to :tag
belongs_to :post
```

After that, calling tag.posts should return all posts for a given tag.